# Shifted image in video

Tags: c++, video, opencv

I'm trying to write a video using opencv's VideoWriter. Here's code:

```
int main() {
    //read image from file:
    Mat image(cvLoadImage("temp.bmp"));
    //create videowriter (DivX codec):
    VideoWriter record("output.avi", CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), 30, image.size(), true);
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        //write frame to video:
        record<<image;
    }
}
```

This is image (temp.bmp), that I'm trying to write:
[image: input]

(I can upload original bmp file but even with this png result is the same - see below).

But when I open video (output.avi), I see this:
[image]

Why video is so shifted?
I have tried [different codecs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/cpp/highgui/VideoWriter) and convert image to different types using [cvtColor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor) (CV_BGR2xxx) but with no luck.

Is it time to report a bug?

Comment: Have you tried 'DIB' format ?

Comment: @Eric, Thanks for reply. I have tried `CV_FOURCC('D','I','B',' ')` but got this error: `OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally.) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open`. I did womething wrong?

Comment: Its very difficult to say what's wrong. But just a wild guess, this could be because the CvLoadImage is not able to remove the line padding in bitmap files. You can try a different .bmp image with a width of multiple of 4,(in that case there will be no line padding) and then tell if there is any difference.

Comment: @nac, that's right! When I expanded image's width from 1922 to 1924 video started to write properly. Thanks!

Comment: that's great! It's a little funny that they managed to write so many codecs and parsers, but left on such a common thing. In all bitmap documentation they highlight and bold the line 'beware of line padding'. Anyways, if you want to eliminate this problem once and for all, use .bmp's with 'alpha channel'[R-G-B-A]. They never require padding for any dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested this issue on OpenCV 2.4.1 (previously I tested it on version 2.3.1) and it works fine! It seems that it was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you:

```
VideoWriter out_capture("video.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 30, RESULTS[0].size() ,true);

for(int i = 0 ; i < RESULTS.size() ; i++)
{
    Mat img;
    RESULTS[i].copyTo(img);

    if(img.empty())
        break;
    out_capture << img;
}
```

`RESULTS` is a vector storing all my images.

Here is a frame of the video:
[image]

What I want is this:
[image]